# how to Implement a script that decomposes a sample database into two different databases?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this difficult question for my database subject. The exact question is

> Implement SQL script solution3.sql that decomposes a sample database created by a script dbcreate.sql into the databases "NSW" and "VIC" located at the different Oracle servers.
>
> The "NSW" database site supposed to contain information about the information of departments and employees located in the state NSW.
>
> The "VIC" database supposed to contain information about the departments and
>   employees from the state of VIC.

what would the code look like to implement such a script? im a bit lost and confused.(i know how to connect to oracles im more lost on the script)

heres the code for the dbcreate. I believe what the question is asking is any instance of a record thats attatched to 'NSW' is copied to the NSW database and any instance of a record thats attatched to 'VIC" is copied to the VIC database

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
    DName       VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Department name        */
    Manager#    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Department manager number  */
    MSDate      DATE,             /* Manager start date         */
    CONSTRAINT Department_PK PRIMARY KEY(D#),
    CONSTRAINT Department_CK UNIQUE(DName)
);


CREATE TABLE DeptLocation (
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
    Address     VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL, /* Department location    */
    CONSTRAINT DeptLocation_PK PRIMARY KEY(D#, Address),
    CONSTRAINT DeptLocation_FK FOREIGN KEY(D#) REFERENCES Department(D#)
);


CREATE TABLE Employee (
    E#      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
    Name        VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Employee name      */
    DOB     Date,             /* Date of birth      */
    Address     VARCHAR2(50),         /* Home address       */
    Sex     CHAR,             /* M-Male, F-Female       */
    Salary      NUMBER(7,2),          /* Salary         */
    Super#      CHAR(5),          /* Supervisor number      */
    D#      NUMBER(5),        /* Department number      */
    CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY(E#),
    CONSTRAINT Employee_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (Super#) REFERENCES Employee(E#),
    CONSTRAINT Employee_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (D#) REFERENCES Department (D#)
);


CREATE TABLE Project (
    P#      NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, /* Project number     */
    PTitle      VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Project title      */
    Sponsor     VARCHAR2(30),         /* Project sponsor name   */
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
    Budget      NUMBER(10,2)    NOT NULL, /* Project budget     */
    CONSTRAINT Project_PK PRIMARY KEY(P#),
    CONSTRAINT Project_FK FOREIGN KEY (D#) REFERENCES Department(D#),
    CONSTRAINT Project_CK UNIQUE (PTitle)
);


CREATE TABLE WorksOn (
    E#      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
    P#      NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, /* Project number     */
    Hours       NUMBER(3,1) NOT NULL, /* Working hours per week */
    CONSTRAINT WorksOn_PK PRIMARY KEY(E#, P#),
    CONSTRAINT WorksOn_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(E#) REFERENCES Employee(E#), 
    CONSTRAINT WorksOn_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(P#) REFERENCES Project(P#)
);


CREATE TABLE Dependent (
    E#      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
    DName       VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Dependent name     */
    Sex     CHAR,             /* Dependent sex, M-Male, F-Female */
    DOB     DATE,             /* Date of birth      */
    Relationship    VARCHAR2(10),         /* Relationship with the employee */
    CONSTRAINT Dependent_PK PRIMARY KEY(E#, DName),
    CONSTRAINT Dependent_FK FOREIGN KEY(E#) REFERENCES Employee(E#),
    CONSTRAINT Dependent_CK CHECK (Relationship IN ('SON', 'DAUGHTER', 'SPOUSE', 'OTHER'))
);
```

I have also set up the appropriate select statements. Change NSW for VIC if needed

```
/* NSW */
SELECT * 
FROM DEPTLOCTAION
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE %NSW%;

SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE %NSW%;

SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON DEPARTMENT.D# = EMPLOYEE.D#
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%NSW%';

SELECT * FROM PROJECT
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON PROJECT.D# = EMPLOYEE.D#
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%NSW%';

SELECT * FROM WORKSON
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON WORKSON.E# = EMPLOYEE.E#
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%NSW%';

SELECT * FROM DEPENDENT
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON DEPENDENT.E# = EMPLOYEE.E#
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%NSW%';
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the code of the script `dbcreate.sql` ?

Comment: @Abra ive added it to the question

Comment: Where does _NSW_ or _VIC_ appear in the database? In which table and in which column of that table? My guess is column `Address` in table `DeptLocation`.

Comment: @Abra they appear in address in deptLocation and address in Employee

Comment: The author of the question seems unclear about the difference between the terms *'schema'*, *'database'* and *'instance'*. It's also not clear whether the part about the schemas being *located at the different Oracle servers* is relevant to the question. (Are you supposed to use export/import utilities?) Also the use of `char` does not inspire confidence - it's a type that professionals avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted to using a SQL*Plus script? Are you allowed to create a database link? If both of these assumptions are true, here's a basic example of how I would tackle the problem.

```
CONNECT myschema/mypass@test

CREATE TABLE DeptLocation (
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL,
    Address     VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO DeptLocation (
d#, address) VALUES (1, 'NSW');

INSERT INTO DeptLocation (
d#, address) VALUES (2, 'VIC');

COMMIT;

CONNECT myschema/mypass@dev

CREATE TABLE DeptLocation (
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL,
    Address     VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
);

CONNECT myschema/mypass@test

CREATE DATABASE LINK dev_dblink
   CONNECT TO myschema IDENTIFIED BY mypass
   USING 'dev';

INSERT INTO DeptLocation@dev_dblink (d#, address)
SELECT *
FROM DeptLocation
WHERE address LIKE '%VIC%';

DELETE
FROM DeptLocation
WHERE address LIKE '%NSW%';

COMMIT;
```